# Problem deploying Rails 3.1 project to Heroku: Could not find a JavaScript runtime

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am having trouble deploying a rails 3.1 beta project to heroku. The problem happened at the database migration step. When I ran:

```
heroku rake db:migrate
```

I got error message:

```
> rake aborted! 

> Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See
> https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs
> for a list of available runtimes.

> /app/Rakefile:5 

> (See full trace by running task with --trace) 

> (in /app)
```

But I can successfully run the application locally, and I do have nodejs installed. Any idea why?

Here my gem list:

```
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.1.0.beta1)
actionpack (3.1.0.beta1, 3.0.7)
activemodel (3.1.0.beta1, 3.0.7)
activerecord (3.1.0.beta1)
activeresource (3.1.0.beta1)
activesupport (3.1.0.beta1, 3.0.7)
ansi (1.2.5)
arel (2.1.0)
bcrypt-ruby (2.1.4)
builder (3.0.0, 2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.13)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.1.0)
configuration (1.2.0)
daemon_controller (0.2.6)
erubis (2.7.0, 2.6.6)
execjs (1.0.0, 0.3.3)
fastthread (1.0.7)
heroku (2.1.4)
hike (1.0.0)
i18n (0.6.0beta1, 0.5.0)
jquery-rails (1.0.1)
json (1.5.1)
json_pure (1.5.1)
launchy (0.4.0)
mail (2.3.0)
mime-types (1.16)
minitest (1.6.0)
multi_json (1.0.1)
mysql (2.8.1)
mysql2 (0.3.2)
oauth (0.4.4)
passenger (3.0.7)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.3.0.beta, 1.2.2)
rack-cache (1.0.1)
rack-mount (0.7.2, 0.6.14)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.0, 0.5.7)
rails (3.1.0.beta1)
railties (3.1.0.beta1)
rake (0.8.7)
rdoc (2.5.8)
rest-client (1.6.1)
rubygems-update (1.8.1)
sass (3.1.1)
simplegeo (0.5.1)
sprockets (2.0.0.beta.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.3)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3)
term-ansicolor (1.0.5)
therubyracer-heroku (0.8.1.pre3)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3)
treetop (1.4.9)
turn (0.8.2)
tzinfo (0.3.27)
uglifier (0.5.1)
```

Answer (score 50):

You need a JavaScript engine for Rails 3.1 (heroku doesn’t have one), and it appears that the JavaScript engine that works with Heroku is the [rubyracer for heroku](https://github.com/aler/therubyracer-heroku).

Rails uses execjs to execute JavaScript and execjs supports 7 JavaScript engines.  Node.js is one, and rubyracer is one.

[Gerred Dillon](http://www.quickleft.com/blog/rails-31-sprockets-and-heroku) had a similar problem and wrote about it.  In the comment section a point was raised about making this a production only change, since you already have nodejs as your local JavaScript engine.  So the relevant code is:

```ruby
group :production do
  gem 'therubyracer-heroku', '0.8.1.pre3'
end
```

**UPDATE:** Heroku has a new stack, called [Cedar](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar), that they recommend for Rails 3.1.0. (Run `heroku stack` to see what stack your app is on.) Heroku also has a [doc](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#upgrading_from_previous_rails_31_releases) about upgrading to Rails 3.1.0 rc5. They recommend **not** using the ‘therubyracer-heroku’ gem anymore as it’s not necessary with rc5.

If you are upgrading from an older rc, make sure to update your config/application.rb file, and also run this command:

```
heroku config:add PATH=vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:bin
```

Apparently, this is set in new apps, but existing apps have not set this PATH.

Comment: I have just attempted this, but the file fails to install on heroku. A google of the issue shows lots of similar issues.

Comment: also, it may be necessary to update line 3 in config/initializers/session_store.rb to something like MyApp::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, :key => '_blahblahblah_session'

Comment: I do have this gem installed and used in Gemfile.
# Asset template engines
gem 'sass'
gem 'coffee-script'
gem 'uglifier'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'therubyracer-heroku', '0.8.1.pre3', :platforms => :ruby

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
end

Comment: Sorry I have to reformat my previous comment a bit. I do have this gem installed and used in Gemfile: 
gem 'therubyracer-heroku', '0.8.1.pre3', :platforms => :ruby
 But it didn't work.

Comment: Heroku has a stack now that comes with node.js which probably takes care of this issue.  Check it out at http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cedar

Answer (score 8):

You don't necessarily need a JavaScript runtime to deploy Rails 3.1 beta to heroku.

The JavaScript runtime is only required if you are minifying javascript on deployment (i.e., via the **uglifier** gem) or if you are using coffee-script.

It looks like this javascript runtime dependency will not be there for the 3.1 final release.

In case you don't mind not minifying your javascript (and also if you're not using coffee-script), then you can comment out the **coffee-script, uglifier and execjs** gems in the Gemfile and also comment out **config.assets.js_compressor** in your **production.rb** and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 5):

As of the date of this post you still need to specify

gem 'therubyracer-heroku', '0.8.1.pre3'

in your gemfile in order to successfully deploy a Rails 3.1 app to Heroku's Cedar platform.

While it is possible to deploy Node apps to the Cedar platform, Node itself is not present on the Cedar stack when deploying Rails apps, so you have to bundle your own javascript runtime.

For now.

I know the people on the Rails side of things are working to remove the dependency on having a js runtime, http://yehudakatz.com/2011/06/14/what-the-hell-is-happening-to-rails/ 
and I'm sure that Heroku is also looking into ways to make Rails 3.1 deployments just work.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it happened after successful upload to Heroku and accessing the page.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes.
2012-01-09T08:21:19+00:00 app[web.1]:   (in /app/app/assets/javascripts/page.js.coffee)):
```

Setting path using 'heroku config:add PATH blah' didn't help.

"rake assets:precompile" just solved it.

Hope it helps anyone like me!