# Running ruby 1.9.2 on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I'm trying to create a new app on heroku but it seems no matter what I do heroku runs ruby 1.9.1 rather than 1.9.2

I've created my app...

```
heroku create writings --stack cedar
```

Then I've pushed my develop branch to master on heroku for testing

```
git push heroku develop:master
```

But the app runs with errors... looking in the heroku logs.. this seems to be the offending error.

```
 /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-1.1.3/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:43:in `autodetect': Could not find a JavaScript runtime. See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs for a list of available runtimes. (ExecJS::RuntimeUnavailable)
```

Which shows that it's running ruby 1.9.1 does it not?

If I run heroku config it shows...

```
heroku config
DATABASE_URL        => postgres://mxlvaczibv:wMtsU7TrPMQM5n-X5SfX@ec2-50-19-226-179.compute-1.amazonaws.com/mxlvaczibv
GEM_PATH            => vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1
LANG                => en_US.UTF-8
PATH                => vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
RACK_ENV            => production
RAILS_ENV           => production
SHARED_DATABASE_URL => postgres://mxlvaczibv:wMtsU7TrPMQM5n-X5SfX@ec2-50-19-226-179.compute-1.amazonaws.com/mxlvaczibv
```

Is this not showing it is running 1.9.1? I'm totally confused... I thought the cedar stack ran 1.9.2. Any help appreciated.

Thanks, mark.

Comment: check your ruby version by opening a console `$ heroku console` then inside the console, look at the `RUBY_VERSION` constant. (I assume this works on Cedar, but haven't tried it)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It does not show that it is running Ruby 1.9.1. Because the standard library changed very little between 1.9.1 and 1.9.2, the same path is used for both of them. You will notice this is not just on Heroku.

It looks like `execjs` is expecting to have a JS runtime installed on the system. Apparently Celadon Cedar does have one (NodeJS), but it won't work until rails 3.1rc5 arrives. Until then, follow the intructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075961/problem-deploying-rails-3-1-project-to-heroku-could-not-find-a-javascript-runtim/6076852#6076852) answer.

Comment: Thanks! Added rubyracer gem and that got rid of that error. But now I just get a generic Error H10 (App crashed) error for heroku. I'm sure this is something else entirely.

Comment: I think the default stack on heroku uses 1.9.2 now as well.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Ruby 1.9.2 and Heroku as well. I have this in my Gemfile. I remember having some sort of javascript errors when trying to deploy to Heroku before as well, I'm pretty sure this solved it.

```
group :production do
  gem 'therubyracer-heroku',  '0.8.1.pre3'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
heroku create --stack bamboo-mri-1.9.2
```