# Rails 3.1.1 deploy to Heroku failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rubygems, bundler, rails-admin

After upgrading my Rails 3.0.9 app to 3.1.1, I'm getting the following bundler error when pushing to Heroku-cedar stack:

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.1.rc
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle
       Updating git://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git
       Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/........
       Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
       In Gemfile:
       rails_admin (>= 0) ruby depends on
       rails (~> 3.1) ruby
       rails (3.0.9)

 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/rails app

To git@heroku.com:[app].git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:[app].git'
```

I was originally using Bundler 1.0.21 but noticed that Heroku is using 1.1.rc so I removed 1.0.21 from my gemset, installed 1.1.rc, and re-generated my gemfile.lock.

I've tried deleting gemfile.lock and re-generating it with bundle update/bundle install, and have tried removing the rails_admin gem from the gemfile.  I have also tried completely emptying my gemset and reinstalling all the gems.

My gemfile looks like:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '>= 3.1.1'
gem 'pg'
group :assets do
    gem 'sass-rails', "~>3.1.4"
    gem 'coffee-rails', "~>3.1.0"
    gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'rake', '>= 0.9.2.2'
gem 'rails_admin', :git => 'git://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git'
gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 1.0.12'
# haml added to make heroku-cedar happy
gem 'haml'
gem 'formtastic', '>= 1.2.3'
gem 'tabs_on_rails'
gem 'acts_as_list'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
gem 'best_in_place'
# fastercsv added to make heroku-cedar happy
gem 'fastercsv'
gem 'event-calendar', :require => 'event_calendar'
gem 'date_validator'
gem 'nested_form', :git => 'git://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git'
gem 'will_paginate', '>= 3.0.pre4'
gem 'heroku'



# Google analytics gem
group :production do
    gem 'thin'
    gem 'rack-google_analytics', :require => "rack/google_analytics"
end

# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:

gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.6.1", :group => [:test, :development]

group :test do
        gem 'factory_girl_rails'
        gem 'webrat'
        gem 'guard-rspec'
end
```

and gemfile.lock:

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git
  revision: 57f32788f1952bcd633057b4b56b69b51df17610
  specs:
    nested_form (0.1.1)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/sferik/rails_admin.git
  revision: e99d7f8e9002ae7c6b4dddb962174e76f8663400
  specs:
    rails_admin (0.0.1)
      bootstrap-sass (~> 1.4)
      builder (~> 3.0)
      coffee-rails (~> 3.1)
      haml (~> 3.1)
      jquery-rails (= 1.0.16)
      kaminari (~> 0.12.4)
      rails (~> 3.1)
      remotipart (= 1.0)

GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.1.1)
      actionpack (= 3.1.1)
      mail (~> 2.3.0)
    actionpack (3.1.1)
      activemodel (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      rack (~> 1.3.2)
      rack-cache (~> 1.1)
      rack-mount (~> 0.8.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.0.2)
    activemodel (3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
    activerecord (3.1.1)
      activemodel (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      arel (~> 2.2.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.1.1)
      activemodel (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
    activesupport (3.1.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    acts-as-taggable-on (2.1.1)
      rails
    acts_as_list (0.1.4)
    addressable (2.2.6)
    arel (2.2.1)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    best_in_place (1.0.1)
      jquery-rails
      rails (~> 3.1.0)
    bootstrap-sass (1.4.0)
      sass-rails (~> 3.1.0)
    builder (3.0.0)
    cancan (1.6.7)
    coffee-rails (3.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.1.2)
    daemons (1.1.4)
    date_validator (0.6.2)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0, < 3.2.0)
    devise (1.4.9)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.0.3)
      warden (~> 1.0.3)
    diff-lcs (1.1.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    event-calendar (2.3.3)
    eventmachine (0.12.10)
    execjs (1.2.9)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    factory_girl (2.2.0)
      activesupport
    factory_girl_rails (1.3.0)
      factory_girl (~> 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    fastercsv (1.5.4)
    formtastic (2.0.2)
      rails (~> 3.0)
    guard (0.8.8)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    guard-rspec (0.5.2)
      guard (>= 0.8.4)
    haml (3.1.3)
    heroku (2.11.1)
      launchy (>= 0.3.2)
      rest-client (~> 1.6.1)
      rubyzip
      term-ansicolor (~> 1.0.5)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    jquery-rails (1.0.16)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.6.1)
    kaminari (0.12.4)
      rails (>= 3.0.0)
    launchy (2.0.5)
      addressable (~> 2.2.6)
    mail (2.3.0)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.17.2)
    multi_json (1.0.3)
    nokogiri (1.5.0)
    orm_adapter (0.0.5)
    pg (0.11.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.3.5)
    rack-cache (1.1)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-google_analytics (1.0.2)
      rack
    rack-mount (0.8.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.1.1)
      actionmailer (= 3.1.1)
      actionpack (= 3.1.1)
      activerecord (= 3.1.1)
      activeresource (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.1.1)
    railties (3.1.1)
      actionpack (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rdoc (3.11)
      json (~> 1.4)
    remotipart (1.0)
    rest-client (1.6.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    rspec (2.7.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.7.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.7.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.7.0)
    rspec-core (2.7.1)
    rspec-expectations (2.7.0)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.2)
    rspec-mocks (2.7.0)
    rspec-rails (2.7.0)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      rspec (~> 2.7.0)
    rubyzip (0.9.4)
    sass (3.1.10)
    sass-rails (3.1.4)
      actionpack (~> 3.1.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.4)
      sprockets (~> 2.0.0)
      tilt (~> 1.3.2)
    sprockets (2.0.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    tabs_on_rails (2.0.2)
    term-ansicolor (1.0.7)
    thin (1.2.11)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.30)
    uglifier (1.0.4)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)
    warden (1.0.6)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    webrat (0.7.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.2.0)
      rack (>= 1.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.3)
    will_paginate (3.0.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  acts-as-taggable-on
  acts_as_list
  best_in_place
  cancan
  coffee-rails (~> 3.1.0)
  date_validator
  devise
  event-calendar
  factory_girl_rails
  fastercsv
  formtastic (>= 1.2.3)
  guard-rspec
  haml
  heroku
  jquery-rails (>= 1.0.12)
  nested_form!
  pg
  rack-google_analytics
  rails (>= 3.1.1)
  rails_admin!
  rake (>= 0.9.2.2)
  rspec-rails (>= 2.6.1)
  sass-rails (~> 3.1.4)
  tabs_on_rails
  thin
  uglifier
  webrat
  will_paginate (>= 3.0.pre4)
```

gemfile.lock after commenting out rails_admin and bundle update / bundle install:

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/ryanb/nested_form.git
  revision: 57f32788f1952bcd633057b4b56b69b51df17610
  specs:
    nested_form (0.1.1)

GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.1.1)
      actionpack (= 3.1.1)
      mail (~> 2.3.0)
    actionpack (3.1.1)
      activemodel (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      rack (~> 1.3.2)
      rack-cache (~> 1.1)
      rack-mount (~> 0.8.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.0.2)
    activemodel (3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
    activerecord (3.1.1)
      activemodel (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      arel (~> 2.2.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.1.1)
      activemodel (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
    activesupport (3.1.1)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    acts-as-taggable-on (2.1.1)
      rails
    acts_as_list (0.1.4)
    addressable (2.2.6)
    arel (2.2.1)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
    best_in_place (1.0.1)
      jquery-rails
      rails (~> 3.1.0)
    builder (3.0.0)
    cancan (1.6.7)
    coffee-rails (3.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
    coffee-script (2.2.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.1.2)
    daemons (1.1.4)
    date_validator (0.6.2)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0, < 3.2.0)
    devise (1.4.9)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.0.3)
      warden (~> 1.0.3)
    diff-lcs (1.1.3)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    event-calendar (2.3.3)
    eventmachine (0.12.10)
    execjs (1.2.9)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    factory_girl (2.2.0)
      activesupport
    factory_girl_rails (1.3.0)
      factory_girl (~> 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    fastercsv (1.5.4)
    formtastic (2.0.2)
      rails (~> 3.0)
    guard (0.8.8)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    guard-rspec (0.5.2)
      guard (>= 0.8.4)
    haml (3.1.3)
    heroku (2.11.1)
      launchy (>= 0.3.2)
      rest-client (~> 1.6.1)
      rubyzip
      term-ansicolor (~> 1.0.5)
    hike (1.2.1)
    i18n (0.6.0)
    jquery-rails (1.0.16)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    json (1.6.1)
    launchy (2.0.5)
      addressable (~> 2.2.6)
    mail (2.3.0)
      i18n (>= 0.4.0)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.17.2)
    multi_json (1.0.3)
    nokogiri (1.5.0)
    orm_adapter (0.0.5)
    pg (0.11.0)
    polyglot (0.3.3)
    rack (1.3.5)
    rack-cache (1.1)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-google_analytics (1.0.2)
      rack
    rack-mount (0.8.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    rack-ssl (1.3.2)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.1)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.1.1)
      actionmailer (= 3.1.1)
      actionpack (= 3.1.1)
      activerecord (= 3.1.1)
      activeresource (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.1.1)
    railties (3.1.1)
      actionpack (= 3.1.1)
      activesupport (= 3.1.1)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.14.6)
    rake (0.9.2.2)
    rdoc (3.11)
      json (~> 1.4)
    rest-client (1.6.7)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    rspec (2.7.0)
      rspec-core (~> 2.7.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.7.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.7.0)
    rspec-core (2.7.1)
    rspec-expectations (2.7.0)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.1.2)
    rspec-mocks (2.7.0)
    rspec-rails (2.7.0)
      actionpack (~> 3.0)
      activesupport (~> 3.0)
      railties (~> 3.0)
      rspec (~> 2.7.0)
    rubyzip (0.9.4)
    sass (3.1.10)
    sass-rails (3.1.4)
      actionpack (~> 3.1.0)
      railties (~> 3.1.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.4)
      sprockets (~> 2.0.0)
      tilt (~> 1.3.2)
    sprockets (2.0.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    tabs_on_rails (2.0.2)
    term-ansicolor (1.0.7)
    thin (1.2.11)
      daemons (>= 1.0.9)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.6)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
    thor (0.14.6)
    tilt (1.3.3)
    treetop (1.4.10)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.30)
    uglifier (1.0.4)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      multi_json (>= 1.0.2)
    warden (1.0.6)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    webrat (0.7.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.2.0)
      rack (>= 1.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.3)
    will_paginate (3.0.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  acts-as-taggable-on
  acts_as_list
  best_in_place
  cancan
  coffee-rails (~> 3.1.0)
  date_validator
  devise
  event-calendar
  factory_girl_rails
  fastercsv
  formtastic (>= 1.2.3)
  guard-rspec
  haml
  heroku
  jquery-rails (>= 1.0.12)
  nested_form!
  pg
  rack-google_analytics
  rails (>= 3.1.1)
  rake (>= 0.9.2.2)
  rspec-rails (>= 2.6.1)
  sass-rails (~> 3.1.4)
  tabs_on_rails
  thin
  uglifier
  webrat
  will_paginate (>= 3.0.pre4)
```

Comment: When you removed `rails_admin` completely, did it still give you the `rails_admin (>= 0) ruby depends on` stuff?

Comment: Yes, it did.  Don't know why - I completely deleted gemfile.lock after I commented out rails_admin and ran bundle install.

Comment: @hardy12 Gemfile.lock after bundle update / bundle install with rails_admin commented out:
code

Comment: Your `Gemfile.lock` is definitely checked into git, right? (i.e. your `.gitignore` isn't excluding it?)

Comment: It is.  We keep that code on Github, and I can see the updated gemfile.lock when I push to Github repo.

Comment: Have also tried bundle cache, to no avail.  There is an issue raised on the rails admin [repo](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/784); but I haven't been able to find any way to change the version of bundler Heroku uses.  Nor am I convinced that's the source of the issue; I am using 1.1.rc on my local machine and it bundles fine.

Comment: Any other ideas here?  I have tried everything I can think of, including creating a new Heroku cedar app and trying to push to that with rails_admin and formtastic removed (same result).  Have also tried adding 'therubyracer' per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6075961/problem-deploying-rails-3-1-project-to-heroku-could-not-find-a-javascript-runti) thread, though that seems like a different issue.  I've also tried the Bundler troubleshooting steps [here](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/1-0-stable/ISSUES.md) to no avail.

Comment: I'm at a loss. Have you tried contacting Heroku's support?

Comment: Yes - they've escalated the request and are working on it.  I'll update with the result.

Comment: Heroku support copied the gemfile from above into a new app and was able to successfully push it to a new Cedar app.  After I learned that, I copied all the files from my app into a new directory (except .git), initialized a new git repo, and was able to successfully push to Heroku cedar.  I have no idea what the problem is/was, but have found a way around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I resolved this by deleting my .git directory, initialized a new repo with git init and re-committed everything.  Not ideal, but the only way I could solve this.