# Rake aborted! when locally Precompiling Assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, asset-pipeline, precompile

When running `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` on my dev machine I get a rake aborted error:

```
cannot load such file -- rack/google_analytics
```

This is in my gemfile in the production group so isn't installed on my dev machine:

```
group :production do
    gem 'rack-google_analytics', :require => "rack/google_analytics"
end
```

Any ideas how to fix this? I am running rake 0.9.2.2 and Rails 3.2.1. If required, I can provide more info.

Comment: Not sure if you seen this already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020852/rails-3-1-1-deploy-to-heroku-failing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I could resolve this was to comment out the Production group in my gemfile, and then running:

```
bundle install
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Then uncommenting, running bundle install again and pushing to git/deploying with capistrano.

Comment: I'd like to resolve a proper answer, rather than this hack though. The reason I'm precompiling locally is that I can't use `load 'deploy/assets'` in my capfile as the production server chokes from not having devlopment/test group gems (specificially it aborts rake with `no such file to load -- faker`.

So if someone can suggest a better answer, I can set them as the accepted answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

When I changed the following value to true from false (in config/environments/production.rb), I could get rid of the above error

config.assets.compile = true

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work for me, I was still seeing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the reason you are experiencing this is that you had previously done a:

```
bundle install --without production
```

Some versions of bundler cache this command and run it as default. Try running something like this to clear the cache:

```
bundle install --without santa
```

Your next command

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

should work fine again.